# PHP how to skip file upload if file already exist

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a problem with a file upload form. If I submit the form  **without uploading any file**. It thinks the file was uploaded when it was missing.

```php
if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))
{
    $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
    $destination = '../upload/' . $new_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
    return $new_name;
}
```

Comment: By missing do you mean empty file gets updated in the database instead of retaining the old file?

Comment: It will always be set, you need to make sure that error is not `4` as 4 means "nothing uploaded"

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by various ways here is the simplest way to do this

```
if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]) && (int)$_FILES["user_image"]['error']===0)
{
    $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
    $destination = '../upload/' . $new_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
    return $new_name;
}
```

Comment: How dkes this work? Why does this work? Please **edit** your answer.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add this explanation. Thanks.

Comment: kindly correct me if I'm wrong
if there is no error

$_FILES["user_image"]['error'] // return int(0)

this element of $_FILE is also returned 0 which is an int why should I use type casting to convert int into int again? while both data types e.g
$_FILES["user_image"]['error']==0 // return false
int(0)==int(0) //return false

both operands of the operator(==)already have the same datatype why should I use Identical(===) operator?

Comment: no doubt your recommendation is a best practice  thanks